# Error while calling a function with return type Map in Drools

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, drools-flow

I have used a function with a return type as map in Drools . While validating it using validate button in the Guvnor it gives me error

The sample code similar to my code is given below

```
function Map<String,String> MyRule(String a){

Map<String,String> MyMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
MyMap.put("TestKey","TestValue");
return MyMap;

}
```

The Error I am getting while validating is

```
Mismatched input '<' expecting '(' in function Map
```

Comment: I think it's still the case that you can't use generics in DRL functions. So remove the `<String, String>`.

Comment: Absolutely - the parser never caught up.

Comment: does it require a JIRA for drools or is the way it works?

Comment: The Drools people know for sure, but it's not anywhere near top priority.

Comment: Knowing this I also become a drools people now.I hope to know more on Drools now..Thanks..